# BitmapFrameで取得した画像のOrientation適用済確認方法

Tags: .net, exif

`BitmapFrame.Create()`を使って画像を取得しているのですが、画像によってExifのOrientation(回転情報)が適用されていたりいなかったりまちまちです。
例えば、CR2やNEF画像は適用されて回転済みの画像になっているのですが、JPGやORF画像は適用されていない、といった感じです。
.NETでサポートしている画像形式だけであれば手動で区別するのですが、WICで拡張されると対応できません。
取得した画像がOrientation適用済であるかどうかを判別する方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 確認方法ではなく適用方法主体ですが、もしかしたらこれらの記事が参考になるかも。[Using WIC to Quickly Create Scaled Down Bitmap that honors EXIF Orientation Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58061904/9014308), [C# WPF Exifの回転情報を取得して画像を表示する](https://qiita.com/standard-software/items/6d111f73a1a8a075ed4c), [How to determine top-down/bottom-up from WIC decoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62541502/9014308), [How to respect EXIF orientations when creating ID2D1Bitmap1 from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28773370/9014308), [Reading metadata from images in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/688990/9014308)